# Open SharePoint Online documents with custom application

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm currently developing an Add-In for SharePoint Online. This Add-In should add a new content-type in SharePoint and create some custom open and edit actions. When someone opens a document with that content-type, SharePoint should redirect the user to another application, passing the item id along. How do I achieve this? All the tutorials online state that I have to put an .ascx file on the server, which cannot be done in SharePoint Online...

Does someone have a clue? Can someone give me any direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those coming by later, you can use the FileHandler options in Office365: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/using-cross-suite-apps

This works fine if [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10/internal-server-error-on-filehandler/6dbf4a61-3deb-4a67-bd6e-501e73c2f03c) issue is fixed.